# Протокол MySQL на C++

Tags: c++, mysql

В свете поисков способа работать с MySQL пришла интересная идея, а нельзя ли просто посылать текстовый запрос и написать декодер для ответов?

В теории все довольно просто. Возможно ли реализовать это на практике? Есть код или документация?

Есть разные проекты для работы с MySQL с невероятными объемами кода. Мне не требуется так много, достаточно реализовать подключение к серверу, авторизацию и обработку ответов на SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT и DELETE.

Comment: Т.е. Вы предлагает вместо использования готового API городить свой? В чём смысл?

Comment: Уже не предлагаю. Нашел нормальное API http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/ .